# Difference between "in" and "zu" regarding time

Tags: standard-german

Duden gives very similar definitions for "in" and "zu" regarding time.

> "Zu" - "kennzeichnet den Zeitpunkt einer Handlung, eines Geschehens, die Zeitspanne, in der sich etwas abspielt, ereignet"
>
> "In" - "zur Angabe eines Zeitraums, innerhalb dessen etwas geschieht, der Fall ist usw."

How do these differ and when would you use each? How would using one instead of the other change the meaning of what you are trying to say?

Answer (score 1):

"In" is for

1. Seasons

> Ich fliege im Sommer nach Amerika.

2. Months

> Im September habe ich Geburtstag.

3. Years with word "Jahr"

> Ich habe im Jahr 2005 mein Studium abgeschlossen.

4. Limit of time, that action will happen, from present

> Ich komme in zwei Stunden zurück.

5. Required time to do something

> Mein Auto fährt 3000 Kilometer in einer Stunde.

6. Non specific time. Like (80s 90s)

> Der Sänger Freddie Mercury war in den 90er Jahren sehr berühmt.

7. Week

> In der nächsten Woche ziehe ich in eine andere Wohnung ein.

8. Century

> Mozart ist im 18. Jahrhundert geboren worden.

"Zu" is like "until". I think it's always used alternatively with "von...bis(zu)" and might be little misleading. But here you have an example:

> Unsere Praxis bleibt vom 28. Dezember bis (zum) 05. Januar geschlossen.

Comment: Another use case for "zu" is when talking about holidays, for example "zu Ostern" = "at Easter" or "zu Weihnachten" = "at Christmas". This might be something to incorporate into your answer.

Comment: Also, if the adressed time-moment or -frame is a beginning of something. "zum Schulbeginn", "zu Ferienbeginn", "zum Herbst ziehe ich nach Kassel" etc.